# How to recover deleted pictures from a long time

Tags: windows-7, pictures

I have *Windows 7 Ultimate x64bit*.

Two years ago I had *Windows 7 Ultimate* in another language, so I formatted the system and all the old files were not deleted but saved in the folder `windows.old`.

Then I decided to delete them normally. 
I remember the exact location and the name of the folder and everything. I just lost the pictures. They were 3000 pics.

I used *Recuva* and *ShadowExplorer* but they failed to recover them. It seems like they recover only files from the folders I have **AT THE MOMENT** in the system.

This is actually a deleted folder with deleted files into the deleted folder.

How do experts do this? I know there must be a way!

Comment: Long time ago I used a CD called UBCD for Windows and recovered a lot of deleted files.

Answer (score 3):

It is highly unlikely to recover your photos cause the hard drive writes new sectors everyday and it is possibly likely to have overwritten the sectors where the folders with the picture you had which it will make it harder for recovery tools to find them or even impossible at some cases .